# patern and matcher not working

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions, pattern, matcher

I am using regex to find line which starts with 'aaaa'

```
pattern myPattern = pattern.compile('^(aaaa)\b.*');
String a = 'aaaa,777,ttttt,rrrrrr';
a += '\n' + 'tttttt,ttttt,0000';
matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(a);
System.debug(myMatcher.matches()); 

System.debug(myMatcher.groupCount());
System.debug(myMatcher.group());
```

**System.debug(myMatcher.group());** this line is throwing exception no group is found.
I have tested my regex at website https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

Can any one tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `myMatcher.find()`. Calling `matches` just tells you if the expression matches the whole input. Also note that you need to escape your special characters (`\\b`) and you probably want to search only up to the end of the line (`$`). That will only work if you set the multi-line flag, otherwise `$` means end of *string*.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile('(?m)^aaaa\\b.*$')
    .matcher('aaaa,bbbb\ncccc,dddd');
if (m.find())
{
    system.debug(m.groupCount());
    system.debug(m.group());
}
```

Comment: and for a second I thought we had a platform bug, totally thought `System.assert(pattern.matches('^.*$','aaaa\nbbbb'));` should pass, makes complete sense if it's matches is the whole string. Great explanation